# c# clickable row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I came to this thanks to very nice tutorial. But the problem is that page reloads, so click works, but the rest of the code doesnt go through... Any ideas why?

```
 protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
        }
    }
    protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            int index = GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
            string Firstname = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
            string Surname = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
            string ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
            string Occupation = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
            string Place = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;
            string Phone = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;
            string Cellular = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text;
            string Mail = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text;
            Label1.Text = Firstname;
            Label2.Text = Surname;
            Label3.Text = ID;
            Label4.Text = Occupation;
            Label5.Text = Place;
            Label6.Text = Phone;
            Label7.Text = Cellular;
            Label8.Text = Mail;
            Panel1.Visible = true;


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register the [event handler method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onselectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx), f.e. on the aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ContactsGridView"
    DataSourceID="YourGridId" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged"        
    OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" 
    runat="server">
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Aqua" />
  </asp:GridView>
```